# Probability of two pair for a poker dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice, poker

I understand that the well known way to solve this is

1. Choose the rank for the two pairs from 6 options - $6C2$
2. Choose the dice for the first pair - $5C2$
3. Choose the dice for the second pair - $3C2$
4. the 5th roll has to be filled among the remaining $6-2=4$ options

So numerator is $6C2 \cdot 5C2 \cdot 3C2 \cdot 4 = 1800$

The sample space consists has $6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 = 6^5$ options

So probability of two pairs is $1800/6^5 = 0.2315$

However I fail to understand, in the denominator sample space, we do not consider the ordering of the dice, if we were to consider the ordering of the dice, the denominator should be $6^5 \times 5!$, then the numerator makes sense to me , as we consider the ordering of the dice via $5C2$ and $3C2$.

Where is my understanding going incorrect?

Comment: You should use latex in this site

Comment: Latex basic tutorial see here : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Imagine if you will that the five dice are all colored differently.  In such a scenario we have $6^5$ outcomes of rolling the five dice... pick which of the six outcomes the *red* die showed, followed by picking which of the six outcomes the *blue* die showed, etc...

Comment: IF you were to insist that the denominator be that we were talking about the dice all being different colored, and rolled one at a time in any of the possible orders, and so we needed to keep track of all $6^5\cdot 5!$ possibilities... then you *must also care about that for the numerator!*  The numerator will need an extra $5!$ to account for this as well, but of course the $5!$ in the numerator will cancel with the $5!$ in the denominator and so to save time and effort we typically will ignore this and not include it in the first place.

Comment: If this is still hard to see... then consider the related problem where we talk about throwing five "*one-sided dice*" (*if you dislike this as a theoretical concept, then consider a six-sided die, but where all sides show a $1$*) and asking what the probability is that you get a five-of-a-kind with these dice.  Obviously the probability should be $1$.  According to your broken logic the answer would have been $\dfrac{1\cdot \binom{5}{5}}{1^5\cdot 5!}\neq 1$ which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: oh I get it, nice perspective. Thanks JMoravitz